# Vue2: About data binding, when are references updated?

Tags: vue.js

I have data in a `parent` Vue which is passed as a `prop` to a `child` view. If the data is changed in the parent, exactly when does the `child` see this change?

I see that this is not instantaneous.

In the fragment below, I pass a parent's `data` as a `prop` to the `child`. `data` is then incremented in the `parent` and the `event` is broadcast to the `child` via a `bus`. The `child` reads the `parent` `data` and sees the older value, not the just increment value.

```
<div id="wrapper">
  data in parent: {{ data }}
  <child :data="data" :bus="bus"></child>
  <button @click="incrementParentData">
    Increment parent data
  </button>
</div>

var Child = {
  template: '<div>data ref in child: {{ data }}</div>',
  props: ['data', 'bus'],

  created: function() {
    var self = this;
    this.bus.$on('parentDataChanged', function(data) {
      alert("data ref in child $on handler:" + self.data);
    });
  }
}

new Vue({
  el: '#wrapper',

  data: function() {
    return {
      data: 1,
      bus: new Vue()
    }
  },

  components: {
    'child': Child
  },

  methods: {
    incrementParentData: function() {
      this.data = this.data + 1;
      alert("data in parent incremented to:" + this.data);
      this.bus.$emit("parentDataChanged", this.data);
    }
  }
})
```

JSFiddle: [here](http://jsfiddle.net/gmanish/centxnx1/4)

Questions:

1. When will the `child` see the change?
2. What do I have to do to see the updated values in the `child` inside the `$on` handler?

PS: I'm passing the changed value as `argument` to the `$emit`, but in my real world case, the child does not need to know anything about what data in the parent changed. All the child has to do is take the parent's data and pass it to a backend api.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the problem is that you don't need to use a bus to catch when a prop has changed.

What you are looking for are watchers, it will be triggered as soon as the prop being watch changes.

You can read more about watchers on the vuejs documentation.

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Watchers

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Beautiful! I had this feeling all along that I was missing something basic :)